# how to write VAR.P excel function in PHP

Tags: php, excel, variance

I'm trying to cacluate the variance of an array in PHP and I can' use built in "stats_variance" function. 
I've searched a lot and found a few functions in php to calculate Variance But the problem is that the number that "VAR.P" excel functions calculates is way different in php.
This is my Array of data :

```
1153680
1118118
1118912
1116187
1068844
1028538
1028538
988121
970411
973495
938557
938550
926133
959840
959841
986759
986759
1002125
995177
968461
987475
1017662
1021445
1047763
1043253
1020218
977923
977923
980571
979106
956817
917406
878101
878094
845952
820505
797824
769385
741932
741902
726137
708995
690126
668906
645763
645723
626389
624527
623260
607855
597254
597069
583344
569674
573903
567532
547658
545661
532522
521267
520108
508879
512900
512903
502077
505943
494479
502694
520211
520210
520059
535684
549185
555167
555165
543926
529170
515452
505676
523850
524394
517911
503306
498856
480875
478755
478754
472119
476812
472749
461988
459079
447151
454618
452842
445894
440199
438880
428216
426184
427139
420668
418312
417001
411211
406008
409807
410694
409962
399445
395912
392038
375650
359807
353807
358843
365815
367334
384099
377012
375547
369729
367632
361088
362259
359365
356721
353996
350322
346870
344487
344115
343291
339386
339434
335792
332567
327624
322527
320814
320194
318670
314587
311230
309643
308477
305774
305622
304997
304688
302726
302340
306885
307094
306655
303944
302795
305858
305333
304676
308960
308730
309661
305969
303449
303453
305807
308314
302173
301391
309640
308978
319871
326190
322059
313049
314469
320909
320208
327305
326117
326098
324705
318250
320023
314409
312206
311471
297712
294166
302082
305917
302395
304460
299930
296731
294601
290178
285573
283062
```

And the calculated variance in excel using VAR.P function is "61222801119"

This is one of the functions that I have tried

```
function getVariance1($arr){
$arr_size=count($arr);
$mu=array_sum($arr)/$arr_size;
$ans=0;
foreach($arr as $elem){
    $ans+=pow(($elem-$mu),2);
}
return sqrt($ans/$arr_size);
```

}

which returns "1633416980.1583"  that is way wrong. 
What's the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found the maths behind Excel's var.p function? Once you have that you can compare it to the maths used in your code and find the difference.

Comment: @SolarMike, Thanks for the reply,I've tried that but I couldn't it.